# VBA Macro: Trying to code "if two cells are the same, then nothing, else shift rows down"

Tags: vba, excel

**My Goal:** To get all data about the same subject from multiple reports (already in the same spreadsheet) in the same row.

**Rambling Backstory:** Every month I get a new datadump Excel spreadsheet with several reports of variable lengths side-by-side (across columns).  Most of these reports have overlapping subjects, but not entirely.  Fortunately, when they are talking about the same subject, it is noted by a number. This number tag is always the first column at the beginning of each report.  However, because of the variable lengths of reports, the same subjects are not in the same rows.  The columns with the numbers never shift (report1's numbers are always column A, report2's are always column G, etc) and numbers are always in ascending order.

**My Goal Solution:**  Since the columns with the ascending numbers do not change, I've been trying to write VBA code for a Macro that compares (for example) the number of the active datarow with from column A with Column G.  If the number is the same, do nothing, else move all the data in that row (and under it) from columns G:J down a line.  Then move on to the next datarow.

**I've tried:** I've written several "For Each"s and a few loops with DataRow + 1 to and calling what I thought would make the comparisons, but they've all failed miserably.  I can't tell if I'm just getting the syntax wrong or its a faulty concept.  Also, none of my searches have turned up this problem or even parts of it I can maraud and cobble together.  Although that may be more of a reflection of my googling skill :)

**Any and all help would be appreciated!**

Note: In case it's important, the columns have headers.  I've just been using DataRow = Found.Row + 1 to circumvent.  Additionally, I'm very new at this and self-taught, so please feel free to explain in great detail

Comment: You should post the code you've tried

Comment: try looping backwards, as you don't want to find the same data you have just shifted down

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Since the numbers are in ascending order, they will be pushed down until they match, and then ignored.

Comment: @enderland Trying to find some of the code I've tried.  I'm someone who trashes everything too fast

Comment: @Ellen learned a long time ago, never do that.  How do you know that the code you tried 14 attempts ago that was trashed was right except for 1 small thing.  You spend a lot of time rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your objective and this should work. It doesn't use any of the methodology you were using as reading your explanation I had a good idea how to proceed. If it isn't what you are looking for my apologies.

It starts at a predefined column (see FIRST_ROW constant) and goes row by row comparing the two cells (MAIN_COLUMN & CHILD_COLUMN). If MAIN_COLUMN < CHILD_COLUMN it pushes everything between SHIFT_START & SHIFT_END down one row. It continues until it hits an empty row.

```
Sub AlignData()
  Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2       ' So you can skip a header row, or multiple rows
  Const MAIN_COLUMN As Long = 1     ' this is your primary ID field
  Const CHILD_COLUMN As Long = 7    ' this is your alternate ID field (the one we want to push down)
  Const SHIFT_START As String = "G" ' the first column to push
  Const SHIFT_END As String = "O"   ' the last column to push

  Dim row As Long
  row = FIRST_ROW
  Dim xs As Worksheet
  Set xs = ActiveSheet
  Dim im_done As Boolean
  im_done = False
  Do Until im_done
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(xs.Rows(row)) = 0 Then
      im_done = True
    Else
      If xs.Cells(row, MAIN_COLUMN).Value < xs.Cells(row, CHILD_COLUMN).Value Then
        xs.Range(Cells(row, SHIFT_START), Cells(row, SHIFT_END)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Debug.Print "Pushed row: " & row & " down!"
      End If
      row = row + 1
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

I modified the code to work as a macro. You should be able to create it right from the macro dialog and run it from there also. Just paste the code right in and make sure the **Sub** and **End Sub** lines don't get duplicated. It no longer accepts a worksheet name but instead runs against the currently active worksheet.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense looking at it.  However, when I try to use it, VBA keeps insisting an 'End Sub' is needed after the 'const's.  I've never used 'Function' before, am I missing something?  I just read that these sorts of functions should be dropped directly into a module.  I did that, but I'm not sure how to call it properly

Comment: That code pasted into a new module will work fine. If you are trying to do it through the macro dialog I will have to change it around a bit. I'll rework it now and edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Awesome! The above code threw my comp into an infinite loop, but I just replace the first If with:
'If xs.Cells(row, MAIN_COLUMN).Value = "" Then
      im_done = True'
and it works great. Thank you so much!